# Web worker Integration

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to use web worker to handle my zipcode checker function, I haven't worked with web worker before so the concept is new to me

This is my zipcode function

``

```
function checkZipCode() {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(document.getElementById('zipcode').value < 20000) {
        document.getElementById('zip-result').innerHTML = 'Sorry, we haven’t expanded to that area yet';

    } else if (document.getElementById('zipcode').value >= 20000) {
        document.getElementById('zip-result').innerHTML = 'We’ve got your area covered!'
    } else {
        return null
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need a web worker?

Comment: Its a homework, plus I'm trying to learn more. Thanks

Comment: Web workers can't access or manipulate the DOM. Generally the reason you want to use a web worker is if you need to leverage multiple OS threads or need to do a lengthy CPU bound computation without blocking. Given that this example does very little computation, and is mainly interacting with the DOM, it's a poor choice for using webworkers, and the overhead of spinning them up and communicating would make this much slower than the implementation you already have.

Comment: @Ryan Jenkins thank for your answer, I have been reading up on web workers and understand this is not good use of the concept, I just want learn so I'd appreciate a code answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) workers are pretty easy to spin up:

```
//in a JS file
const myWorker = new Worker('./myWorker.js');//worker requested and top-level scope code executed

myWorker.postMessage('hello');

myWorker.addEventListener('message', e => {
  //e.data will hold data sent from worker
  const message = e.data;
  console.log(message); // HELLO
  //if it's just a one-time thing, you can kill the worker
  myWorker.terminate();
}

myWorker.addEventListener('error', e => {//worker might throw an error
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.message, `on line ${e.lineno}`);
});


//myWorker.js

//run whatever you need, just no DOM stuff, no window etc
console.log('this line runs when worker loads');

addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    postMessage(e.data.toUpperCase());//up-case message and send it right back
});
```